# How is std::is_same implemented

Tags: c++, templates

I was wondering how `std::is_same` is implemented in c++. My immediate though was typeid comparisons.

```cpp
typeid(K) == typeid(T)
```

Are actual implementations of the function similar this solution or are they much more sophisticated?

Comment: its much less sophisticated ;)

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) shows a possible implementation.

Comment: I don't like this duplicate (since the original question has nothing to do with this one), but the answer indeed has an example implementation of `std::is_same`...

Comment: Also note `typeid` is runtime evalation, std::is_same must work at compile time.